# Is there a Singapore Airlines transfer desk at Amsterdam airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights, ams, singapore-airlines

*Quick note: I asked a related question here before, but this question is different because it is about Singapore Airlines, and about the transfer desk for that in AMS (Amsterdam), which is different than my previous question.*

I will have a transfer soon in AMS airport (Schiphol airport in Amsterdam) arriving from TLV and continuing to SIN. So a non-Schengen to non-Schengen transfer. The flight to SIN is with Singapore Airlines. The transfer would be on two different tickets (i.e. the incoming flight into AMS from TLV is with one ticket, and the outgoing flight from AMS to SIN is on a separate ticket), and I will be with carry-on only. I am allowed entry in the Netherlands but would just prefer to remain airside.

My questions are:

1. Is there an airside transfer counter for Singapore Airlines that I could use? On the Schiphol website they mention transfer desks, but it isn't really clear to me for what airlines these are available.
2. Is there some document verification or other process I would have to do at a landside check-in desk and thus would have a problem remaining airside?

Note: I will do online check-in if that is available to me, but still wondering about this in the case that there is an issue with online check-in, and also with online check-in I am still concerned about question (2), i.e. whether there would be anything I would need to go to landside check-in to do.

Comment: No real answer so a comment. I've travelled a lot through Schiphol as I live nearby but not for a few years. However, Schiphol is a VERY international airport and Singapore Airlines uses it for quite a few connections to the USA and back home. There are a number of airside transit desks available and I would be totally surprised if they can't handle a Singapore Airlines check-in from transfer. Remember that many airlines use a local agent for check-in at airports where having own staff is too expensive (read almost all destinations). Your best bet would be online check-in anyway.

Comment: And airside - I've never seen any document checks there except for normal procedures of getting onto the flight.

Comment: There are multiple transfer desks and self service transfer stations at AMS, these are not airline specific but operated by the airport itself. AFAIK (as it's always my final destination, living there, I've never needed them) they can handle transfers for pretty much every airline. If they can't, they'll be able to direct you to where you need to go.

Comment: Online check-in seems to be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Singapore airlines is not a Sky Team partner. According to [Schiphol's website](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/at-schiphol/services/transferdesk), airlines that are not part of Skyteam use the following transfer desks: T3, T5 or T9.

According to [the Schiphol map](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/airport-maps), transfer desk T3 is located in the Schengen area, so Singapore Airlines will not use that desk for flights to Singapore. T5 and T9 are in the international area, where T5 is in the E wing and desk T9 is located in the GH hall.

My research [shows](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/departures/SQ323) that Singapore Airlines flight 323 (AMS to SIN) departs from the G wing. As such, you will most likely have to use transfer desk T9, [located here](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/airport-maps#poi-6Jm6JUFT2MU6OSQiy6skE6).

As for your specific question, you would probably not need the transfer desk. If you check in online and have your ticked printed then you can proceed straight to your gate. If you arrive from certain locations, you might need to pass the transfer security check first, but I do not know which specific origins that applies to. In any case, that would just be a check that you do not carry prohibited items on your person or in your carry-on.